# Not able to login to SSH using pubkey from non root user on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7

My user `ftpUser` is setup with a 2048 RSA pair. The root user is able to login using a key (I know... I'm disabling it once this is fixed). File permissions:

```
/home/ftpuser/ drwxrr-----
/home/ftpUser/.ssh/ drwxr--r--r--
/home/ftpuser/.ssh/authorized_keys -rw-r--r--
```

I'm assuming it's a permissions issue, but I'm not really sure. the public key s in the authorized_users file and the private one is on my computer. If I put the public key in the root user's authorized_keys file it can login under root.

My sshd_config file has `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys` so, that should be right. I also tried with a different user, which had the same issue.

Comment: ssh_config: https://pastebin.com/ryAKyhwr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I named the file /home/ftpUsers/.ssh/authorized_users instead of /home/ftpUsers/.ssh/authorized_keys. Stupid mistake...